# Heroku/ruby on rails... how can I figure out if I'm running as a worker or a web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, process

I have an app on (ruby/rails) heroku.  It's running 1 web and 1 worker (for example)
I want to be able to tell what "type" of dyno the app is running under.

I suspect it's a simple thing to tell, but I can't see anything that tells me how to tell.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there's a more elegant way to do this, but you can set an environment variable in your Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec ... PROC_TYPE=web
worker: bundle exec ... PROC_TYPE=worker
```

Then in your rails code, you can check ENV['PROC_TYPE']

EDIT: more detailed Procfile example, typical for a rails app:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT PROC_TYPE=web
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work PROC_TYPE=worker
```

Comment: Where would you put the ENV['PROC_TYPE']  code... I'd like to put it in the "main".   Someplace that run when the app starts...

Comment: I could imagine it being in environment.rb, or maybe an initializer, depends on how you're using it though. Probably want to make sure there's a default in case the environment variable is not set.

Comment: Being new to procfile.. could you expand out the ....  The samples I found have some funky things in them..

Comment: awesome.. that worked like a charm. I put it in my environment.rb... tested for worker.....  I want to spawn other workers in the worker dyno.  I have twenty worker dyno's and most of their time is spent waiting for coms.  Figured fork the workers to PID's on half the dyno's then the worker still waits, but it don't cost me 350$ a month.